# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

Here is my case: i can retrieved the data from the database, but when i run the program and filled up the *Quantity* column (on the third line), the error says: index was out of range. Anyone know why is this happen? (When i tried to fill the *Quantity* column (on third line), the error appeared) <-- shown in the picture below.

Here is the images of my program:
[image: When i tried to fill the *Quantity* column (on third line), the error appeared]

Here is the images of where the error is pointed:
[image]

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sell_System
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        private Form1 firstForm;
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxCodeContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxQuantityContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxDescContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxSubTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
        private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxAllTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Form1 firstForm)
            : this()
        {
            this.firstForm = firstForm;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTextPosition();

            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Code] FROM [Data]", conn);

            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            AutoCompleteStringCollection codesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            while (dReader.Read())
            {
                string numString = dReader[0].ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
                codesCollection.Add(numString);
            }

            dReader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            if (firstForm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                label1.Text = "Code:";
                label1.Location = new Point(60, 125);
                label2.Text = "Welcome to the Selling System.";
                label2.Location = new Point(600, 0);
                label3.Text = "Quantity:";
                label3.Location = new Point(155, 125);
                label4.Text = "Description:";
                label4.Location = new Point(580, 125);
                label5.Text = "Sub Total on Rp:";
                label5.Location = new Point(1020, 125);
                label6.Text = "Total on Rp:";
                label6.Location = new Point(1210, 125);
                label7.Text = "Total on Rp:";
                label7.Location = new Point(1080, 580);
            }

            else if (firstForm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "Kode:";
                label1.Location = new Point(60, 125);
                label2.Text = "Selamat datang di Selling System.";
                label2.Location = new Point(600, 0);
                label3.Text = "Banyaknya:";
                label3.Location = new Point(145, 125);
                label4.Text = "Keterangan:";
                label4.Location = new Point(580, 125);
                label5.Text = "Sub Total di Rp:";
                label5.Location = new Point(1020, 125);
                label6.Text = "Total di Rp:";
                label6.Location = new Point(1210, 125);
                label7.Text = "Total di Rp:";
                label7.Location = new Point(1080, 580);
            }

            //****TextBox for Code****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxCodeContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxCodeContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(25, 150 + (y * 25));
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                textBoxCodeContainer[0][y].AutoCompleteCustomSource = codesCollection;

                Controls.Add(textBoxCodeContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Quantity****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxQuantityContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(100, 50);
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(125, 150 + (y * 25));
                textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

                Controls.Add(textBoxQuantityContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Description****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxDescContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxDescContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxDescContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(750, 50);
                textBoxDescContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(225, 150 + (y * 25));

                Controls.Add(textBoxDescContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Sub Total****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxSubTotalContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxSubTotalContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
                textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(975, 150 + (y * 25));

                Controls.Add(textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][y]);
            }

            //****TextBox for Total****
            for (int y = 0; y <= 16; y++)
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
                textBoxTotalContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(1150, 150 + (y * 25));
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

                Controls.Add(textBoxTotalContainer[0][y]);
            }

//****TextBox for Total All****
            textBoxAllTotalContainer.Size = new Size(175, 50);
            textBoxAllTotalContainer.Location = new Point(1150, 575);
            textBoxAllTotalContainer.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

            Controls.Add(textBoxAllTotalContainer);

        }

        private void UpdateTextPosition()
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Double startingPoint = (this.Width / 2) - (g.MeasureString(this.Text.Trim(), this.Font).Width / 2);
            Double widthOfASpace = g.MeasureString(" ", this.Font).Width;
            String tmp = " ";
            Double tmpWidth = 0;

            while ((tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint)
            {
                tmp += " ";
                tmpWidth += widthOfASpace;
            }

            this.Text = tmp + this.Text.Trim();
        }

        private void UpdateDatas()
        {
            int codeValue = 0;
            int index = 0;

            string query = "SELECT [Description], [Price] FROM [Data] WHERE [Code] IN (";

            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][2].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][3].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][4].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][5].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][6].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][7].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][8].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][9].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][10].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][11].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][12].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][13].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][14].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][15].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][16].Text, out codeValue))
            {
                query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
            }

            query = query + ")";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dReader.Read())
            {
                if (textBoxCodeContainer[0][index].TextLength != 0)
                {
                    this.textBoxDescContainer[0][index].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
                    this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][index].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
                }

                index += 1;
            }

            dReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void UpdatePrice()
        {
            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][0].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][0].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][0].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][1].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][1].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][1].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][1].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][1].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][1].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][2].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][2].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][2].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][2].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][2].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][2].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][3].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][3].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][3].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][3].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][3].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][3].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][4].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][4].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][4].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][4].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][4].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][4].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][5].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][5].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][5].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][5].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][5].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][5].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][6].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][6].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][6].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][6].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][6].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][6].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][7].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][7].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][7].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][7].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][7].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][7].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][8].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][8].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][8].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][8].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][8].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][8].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][9].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][9].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][9].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][9].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][9].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][9].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][10].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][10].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][10].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][10].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][10].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][10].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][11].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][11].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][11].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][11].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][11].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][11].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][12].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][12].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][12].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][12].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][12].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][12].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][13].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][13].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][13].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][13].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][13].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][13].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][14].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][14].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][14].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][14].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][14].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][14].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][15].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][15].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][15].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][15].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][15].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][15].Text;
            }

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][16].Text == "")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][16].Text = "";
            }

            else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][16].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][16].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][16].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][16].Text;
            }
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDatas();
            UpdatePrice();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my problem: **"i am confuse, when i try assign a value for "textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text", the code is working. but, when i tried "textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][one(1)]", the screen stucked in there (I have to stop debugging from Visual Studio)"**

**textBoxTotalContainer contains 17 textboxes, therefore, i used [0][0] to [0][16], and textBoxAllTotalContainer contains 1 textbox, so i just used textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text**

Note: **"Keyword (one), it suppose to be "1" <-- number, i wrote (one), because when i tried changed the [0][(Here supposed to be "1")], the text automatically changed to linked image"**

Issue: **"When i tried the code

```
else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][0].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][0].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text;
            }
```

the textbox for *alltotalcontainer* is on (Total on Rp, the textbox is on after words) in the image shown above, the textboxes for *subtotal* is on (Sub Total on Rp), the textboxes for *totalcontainer* is on (Total on Rp, the textboxes are on below words), the textboxes for *quantitycontainer* is on (Quantity). In code above, shown that textbox 1 on *textboxtotalcontainer* are same with the textbox 1 on *subtotalcontainer*, and *alltotalcontainer* is same with *totalcontainer*.**

But, below code it not working, and the screen stucked on there (the mouse dissappear and i cant do anything, unless i press SHIFT + F5 on Visual Studio):

```
else if (textBoxQuantityContainer[0][1].Text == "1")
            {
                textBoxTotalContainer[0][1].Text = textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][1].Text;
                textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][1].Text;
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: The code that creates the error in the screenshot is different to the code you have posted - why have you posted different code?

Comment: i think that the problem is on that code, because the error says: "parameter name: index"

Comment: `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0]` is initialized with two elements - it does not have an element at index 2. See `for (int y = 0; y <= 1; y++)`. Btw posted code does not match error image; all indexes in `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0]` have been reset to zero.

Comment: Why you didn't use a `DataGridView` control. In your case for showing and editing data it seems much better?

Comment: I doubt this code builds at all. `textBoxAllTotalContainer` is declared as `List<T>` but later used as a `Control`...

Comment: What do you mean by "builds at all" Mr. NS.X? and doesn't it suppose to used "Control" to adds the textboxes to the screen and display it?

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when you try to access an element in a collection that doesn't exist.

For example, if you have a list of strings...

```
List<string> myList = new List {"one", "two", "three"};
```

...and try to access the fourth element with `myList[3]`, you'll get that error.

Either `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][2]` doesn't exist, or `textBoxTotalContainer[0][2]`. Can't tell from the error in your picture. Place a breakpoint on that line and check both objects.

Comment: Actually. one of the following does not exists: `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0]` or `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][2]` or `textBoxTotalContainer[0]` or `textBoxTotalContainer[0][2]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your stop condition is wrong.
you have the following code for initializing `textBoxAllTotalContainer`:

```
        //****TextBox for Total All****
        for (int y = 0; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            textBoxAllTotalContainer.Add(new List<TextBox>());
            textBoxAllTotalContainer[0].Add(new TextBox());
            textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][y].Size = new Size(175, 50);
            textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][y].Location = new Point(1150, 575);
            textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][y].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);

            Controls.Add(textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][y]);
        }
```

Note that the loop is itterating only twice.
Therefore `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][0]` and `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][1]` are created.

but when you try to access `textBoxAllTotalContainer[0][2]` you hit the exception because the location is really out of the list's range as the exception specifies.

Comment: Hi Avi Turner, i already changed the code from an array to not using an array (for textbox for total all, please refer to the question above), and now i am confuse, when i try assign a value for **"textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][0].Text"**, the code is working. but, when i tried **"textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text = textBoxTotalContainer[0][1].Text"**, the screen stucked in there (I have to stop debugging from Visual Studio)

Comment: textBoxTotalContainer contains 17 textboxes, therefore, i used [0][0] to [0][16], and textBoxAllTotalContainer contains 1 textbox, so i just used textBoxAllTotalContainer.Text

Comment: @Fuhans I am not sure I understand what you mean by "`the screen stucked in there (I have to stop debugging from Visual Studio)`" Also, can you please clarify what is the issue? Is it still the same exception you got in your original post?

Comment: I mean, when i run the program, the screen stucked. The mouse cursor disappear, and i cannot do anything, unless i have to go back to visual studio and press SHIFT + F5 on there or stop debugging. I will posted the issue on my question above.

Thanks sir